# Automatic Detection of EC2 Instance ssh/sudo User for Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, sudo

I have a mixed set of AWS EC2 instances, some have 'ubuntu' and some have 'ec2-user' as the default ssh/sudo user. A few others are Windows but I'm willing to ignore those for now.
I want to manage them all with ansible using dynamic inventory - I'm using the aws_ec2 plugin - and I need a way to detect the proper ssh/sudo user and associate it with the instance.
Is there a plugin, script, or best practice for creating a mixed-sudo dynamic inventory?

One possibility I've thought of is to run a script that attempts a "root" login to each instance and grabs the proper user name from the usual output (see output below). Then I could store the username as a tag on the instance.

Please login as the user "ec2-user" rather than the user "root".

Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root".

This seems to do that trick

```sh
for HOST in $(ansible --list-hosts all |grep -v hosts);do
  timeout 2 ssh -Tq root@${HOST} | awk -F \" '{ print $2; exit}'
done
```

Where `ansible --list-hosts` returns the private IP of the hosts.

Another idea would be to somehow have ansible try the 2nd name if the first one fails.

This should be a common problem but I have not found any ready-made solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a finite number of AMIs? If so, that can be used to set `ansible_user:` in `pre_tasks:` or similar initialization code (with the assumption there are no helpful EC2 tags on the instances). Another alternative would be `- {ignore_errors: yes,  raw: whoami, vars: {ansible_user: ec2-user}, register: is_ec2_user}` plus `- set_fact:` type deal. I for sure would not advocate having a custom shell script run outside of ansible which does the kind of discovery you're talking about

Comment: Thanks @mdaniel .  There are almost as many AMIs as instances, except where the instances are managed by an autoscale group. I am new to the organization and am the first one to attempt to organize the infrastructure, which has been managed by the devs until now. Also, I have used Chef for years but this is my first foray into Ansible. As such, I didn't fully understand the "{...}" example you gave but I will look into trying to understand it.